# How to edit databound combobox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

In my winForm application I have added databound combobox column in a datagridview. User needs to be able to select an item from dropdown list or write in the combobox. But it wouldn't let me write in the combobox as datasource is set. This is my code:

```
var entityModel= new AdminEntities();
var filterPractice = (from b in entityModel.FILTER where b.PRACTICE != null select b.PRACTICE).Distinct().OrderBy(y => y);
dgvCboColumn(filterPractice, "PRACTICE");
private void dgvCboColumn(dynamic item, string colName)
    {
        int i = dgvLoadTable.Columns[colName].Index;
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        dgvCol.DataSource=item;
        dgvCol.DataPropertyName = colName;
        dgvLoadTable.Columns.Insert(i, dgvCol);
        dgvLoadTable.Columns[i].HeaderText = dgvLoadTable.Columns[i + 1].HeaderText;
        dgvLoadTable.Columns[i + 1].Visible = false;
        dgvLoadTable.Columns.RemoveAt(i + 1);
    }
  private void HandleEditShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        var cbo = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (cbo == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        cbo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
        cbo.Validating -= HandleComboBoxValidating;
        cbo.Validating += HandleComboBoxValidating;
    }
    private void HandleComboBoxValidating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var combo = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
        if (combo == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (!combo.Items.Contains(combo.Text)) 
        {
            var comboColumn = this.dgvLoadTable.Columns[this.dgvLoadTable.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
            combo.Items.Add(combo.Text);
            comboColumn.Items.Add(combo.Text);
            this.dgvLoadTable.CurrentCell.Value = combo.Text;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how can I make the combobox editable, please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can manually get the items frm datasource using Oledb or Ado recordset nd fill de comboBox manually by using for loops.. so basically you can also edit the items..